# Is there any API to create Addresss and wallet as well as make transfer for ETC (Ethereum Classic)?

Tags: addresses, ethereum-classic, explorer-api, exchange-api

There is balance checking, transaction list and transaction receipt getting APIs available for Ethereum Classic (ETC)?

Is ETC coin is only available on Ethereum Classic or its listed block explorer only?

Answer (score 1):

You can use web3.js as it is the same process for ethereum and ethereum classic to interact with the blockchain. There are also libraries for creating accounts and wallets from ethereumjs.

Comment: Yes it has same process but previously I've tested transfer of an ETC using web3.js library. I was unable to do transfer. It would be great if you please elaborate some steps or example to utilise web3.js for ETC.